# How to open a page and run the jQuery within it in a Chrome extension

Tags: jquery

I've written a Chrome extension that is using jQuery. When I'm on a specific web site (online and not local) and press F4 the extension opens a new tab and loads a page from a local web server. This part is working fine.

Once the new page is open I want to run a jQuery `click` within it, but I'm struggling to work out how to do this. So far I have:

```
console.log ('F4 Pressed')
window.open('http://192.168.1.100/testserver', '_blank');
window.onload = $('#button').click()
```

When I press F4 the console log shows F4 was been pressed, the new tab opens and loads the page but nothing else happens.

If I go to the test server and at the console run `$('#button').click()` the function `showFrom(local)` is run and the local form is shown so I know the `click` command is correct.

Can anyone advise me on how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trigger the event on the window you opened, not the current window. To do that store the reference to the child window returned from `window.open()` and use it to call `addEventListener()`. Something like this:

```
var childWin = window.open('http://192.168.1.100/testserver', '_blank');
childWin.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  $('#button').click();
});
```

Also note that it's possible the event will have fired *before* you can attach the event. In which case you could remove the `addEventListener()` call and just invoke the `click()` directly.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this but it seems to do the same as I've currently got. The new page opens but the click doesn't appear to have happened.  How do I invoke the `click()` directly ?

Comment: Thanks got this sorted, realised I had a typo which was stopping it run !